# How to access a hashtable's first value without knowing the key?

Tags: vb.net, hashtable

After reading a config file during installation, I am saving the web services `url` into a `Hashtable` to test the connectivity to those services.

Before going through all the values I saved, I want to test just the first value. The keys I am using are the whole `xml` node containing the service `url` so it's unknown to me.

I didn't know much about `Hashtable` first, so I tried accessing it using an index. Assuming `ht` is a populated `Hashtable`, I tried this:

```
Dim serviceUrl as String = ht(0).Value
```

Which obviously failed since there's no `key` equal to `0`, and the `serviceUrl` is just a `Nothing`.

Then I tried to access first element using:

```
Dim firstEntry as DictionaryEntry = ht(ht.Keys(0).ToString())
' Also tried this:
' Dim firstEntry as DictionaryEntry = ht(ht.Keys(0))
```

In both cases I got an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I ended up using a `For Each` and exiting the loop directly after first iteration.

```
For Each entry As DictionaryEntry In ht
    Dim serviceUrl as String = entry.Value
    'Use it and exit for.
    Exit For
Next
```

Well, this looks really awful.

After some time debugging and looking around, I used an array to hold the keys values:

```
Dim arr as Object() = new Object(100){}
'Copy the keys to that array.
ht.Keys.CopyTo(arr,0)

'Now I can directly access first item from the Hashtable:
Dim serviceUrl as String = ht(arr(0))
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach.

**Is there any direct/clean way to access first item from a `Hashtable`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Keys` property is an `ICollection`, not an `IList`, so it can't be indexed.  `ICollection` is basically just `IEnumerable` with a `Count` property, so you should treat is the same way as an `IEnumerable`.  That means enumerating it to get the first item.  You can use LINQ:

```
Dim firstKey = myHashtable.Keys.Cast(Of Object)().FirstOrDefault()
```

or you can go old-school:

```
Dim firstKey As Object

For Each key In myHashtable.Keys
    firstKey = key
    Exit For
Next
```

If the collection may be empty, you can use the Count property to test first.

Comment: I did go old-school at the end. Just felt it wasn't the right way.

Comment: It feels wrong because you're supposed to know what the keys are so you shouldn't have to do it this way. A Hashtable it's generally pointless if you don't know the keys.

Comment: With that being said, it just occurs to me that we're not using the keys anyways. This is just a legacy code where I was trying to add a new functionality. It's better to use a List or an Array here. I guess a whole re-factor is better. Thank you.

Comment: I ended up refactoring the code to use a `List(Of String)` instead of a `Hashtable`, since we're not using the keys for any purpose. Thank you.